# How to implement a Converter

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a list of objects that I'm binding to the screen.  One of the properties is isPurchased.  It is a Boolean type.

I don't have a lot of experience with converters so I'm finding this a little difficult.  I have 2 questions.

The 1st question is regarding syntax.  I copied this example from [here](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/10/10/winrt-app-guide-step-11-using-a-valueconverter-to-work-with-element-visibility/).

```
   public class purchasedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
       public object Convert(inAppPurchases value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

If the `isPurchased == true` then I'd like to set the background color to my stackpanel to a different color.

I changed `object value` to `inAppPurchases value` on the Convert method.  However, no matter what I tried I could not get a reference to a Background.

I think I want to `return Background="somecolor"`

My 2nd question (assuming I can do the 1st part), is I'm using StandardStyles.xaml which comes with the Microsoft WinRT projects  So my converter would exist there.

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Background="CornflowerBlue" Orientation="Vertical" Height="130"
 Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
```

However, like I said I've tried this before but I wasn't able to figure out how to add the convert to my .xaml file.  Where would I reference the converter?  Is it on the StandardStyls.xaml or the main .xaml that I'm viewing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You know that you are asking about a [data binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)?

Comment: I'm just trying to get familiar with converters.  I did not know that I was asking for a data binding converter.  Do you have any references between the different types?

Comment: In the converter you would cast the passed in `object value` parameter to the actual type of the binding *source* object, and return an object that can be assigned to the binding *target* type. But all that only makes sense if you actually have a binding somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Background` property of `StackPanel` is type of `Brush` ([Panel.Background msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background.aspx)) , so we can return object of type `SolidColorBrush` from `Convert` method.

Your converter should look like this:

```
class PurchasedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // isPurchased is bool so we can cast it to bool
        if ((bool)value == true)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Next you must create instance of this converter in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <con:PurchasedConverter x:Key="pCon" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And now you can use this converter to binding `Background` property in `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical" Height="130"
         Background="{Binding isPurchased, Converter={StaticResource pCon}}" 
         Margin="0,0,5,0" >            
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed.  I took out the datatemplate I was using out of the standardstyles.xaml and put it in the page I'm working with and everything worked perfectly.